# pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN} in custom recipe does not execute

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe

No matter what I do, I cannot get a postinst script to execute. I have a foobar-image.bb with:

```
require recipes-core/images/core-image-base.bb

# Add foobar-tools
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "\
    foobar-tools \
"

pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN} () {
    /bin/touch /home/root/marker_file
}
```

But marker_file is nowhere to be found. I have have tried

- pkg_postinst and pkg_postinst_ontarget (using $D if executed on the host)
- with and without _${PN}
- with and without _append
  but nothing seems to do anything.

I believe the recipe is baked correctly because if I add another IMAGE_INSTALL_append to it, it is added to the image.

I do not use a validated host distribution (ubuntu-22.04). So, although this may be causing it, I cannot change this easily. I would like to know if there may be something else that may be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and the I believe the issue has something to do with the core-image recipe defining its own `pkg_postinst_ontarget` script in one way or another.

What worked for me was creating a separate recipe and defining my post install script there and including the built package in my `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable.

Here is a sample of recipe, note the `ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"` variable.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple postinstall script recipe"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

ALLOW_EMPTY:${PN} = "1"


pkg_postinst_ontarget:${PN}() {
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "blah" > file.txt
}
```

All the best :)